# ElasticSearch with Nest ElasticType on interface

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I would like to share an ElasticSearch type between two classes with a common interface in c# and have a single service that interfaces with the ES type. The issue I am having is that because the ElasticTypeAttribute can only exist on class types the following service inserts on the wrong es type.

Is there a way to achieve the following scenario?

```
public interface I
{
    //...
}

[ElasticType("x")]
public class A : I
{
    //...
}

[ElasticType("x")]
public class B : A, I
{
    //More
}

public class IService
{
    public IIndexResponse Save(I item)
    {
        return ElasticClient.Index(item)
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register your interface to an index and ES type via connection settings:

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(...)
    .MapDefaultTypeIndices(m => m.Add(typeof(IMyInterface), "myindex"))
    .MapDefaultTypeNames(m => m.Add(typeof(IMyInterface), "mytype"));
```